# Creating New Observations From Multiple Month Columns

Tags: pandas, datetime, for-loop

I have a dataframe that does not have a single month column. It is divided into multiple month columns for each record, which prevents me from trending the data with a single month column and amount column. I have not been able to find any tips from the documentation or other questions as to how to accomplish this. Here is my code to create an example dataframe:

```
 import pandas as pd 

 data = [['tom', 1, 3, 4], ['nick', 5, 6, 7], ['juli', 6, 15, 10]] 

 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'mon1', 'mon2', 'mon3'])
```

I want to have a data frame that has a single month column with mon1 as January mon2 as February and mon3 as March. I also would like the dataframe to have the numbers identified with a unique month to be put in an Amount column. I expect the number of observations to be 9 instead of three. For example Tom would have three unique observations because in January he would have an amount of 1 compared to 3 in February. Is it possible to write some kind of for loop to accomplish this?

Expected Example Dataframe:

```
  pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[‘Name’, ‘month’, ‘Amount’])
```

Only with the previous data manipulated to fit the above format.

Comment: can you provide the expected df too?

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long`?

Comment: @anky_91 I provided an example of an expected data frame. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try with below:

```
import calendar
d={'mon'+str(e):i for e,i in enumerate(list(calendar.month_name))}
```

---

```
df_new=df.rename(columns=d).melt('Name',var_name='Month',value_name='Amount')
print(df_new)
```

---

```
   Name     Month  Amount
0   tom   January       1
1  nick   January       5
2  juli   January       6
3   tom  February       3
4  nick  February       6
5  juli  February      15
6   tom     March       4
7  nick     March       7
8  juli     March      10
```

Note: `print(d)`

---

```
{'mon0': '',
 'mon1': 'January',
 'mon2': 'February',
 'mon3': 'March',
 'mon4': 'April',
 'mon5': 'May',
 'mon6': 'June',
 'mon7': 'July',
 'mon8': 'August',
 'mon9': 'September',
 'mon10': 'October',
 'mon11': 'November',
 'mon12': 'December'}
```

Comment: Thank you. After adjusting this to the other dataset this method worked.